# Как передать ссылку на текущий экземпляр класса конструктору его свойства (при объявлении свойства)?

Tags: flutter, dart

К примеру:

я создал класс `One` в котором есть класс `Two` который принимается при создании класса `One`:

```
class One {
  final Two two;
  One({ this.two });
}
```

а в классе `Two` я создаю объект `One` и передаю в качестве параметра созданный класс "Two":

```
class Two {
  One one = One(two: <здесь я хочу передать ссылку на текущий экземпляр "Two">);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Указатель на конечный экземпляр (`this`) недоступен в объявлении свойств класса - так как при объявлении свойств класса, его экземпляра попросту не существует. Класс это как схема/чертеж объекта, но не сам объект.
Получить ссылку на конечный экземпляр класса можно в конструкторе:

```
class One {
  final Two two;
  One({ this.two });
}

class Two {
  One one;
  
  Two() {
    one = One(two: this);
  }
}
```

Или, можно объявить свойство класса как `late` (с поздней/ленивой инициализацией) - тогда `this` уже будет доступен:

```
class Two {
  late One one = One(two: this);
}
```